# How to find the least number that can be written as the sum of two cubes in two different ways?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the least number that can be written as the sum of two cubes in two different ways.
Find the number and show steps in deriving it.

Comment: This is one of mathematician's Srinvasa Ramanujan's challenge problems.

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_(number)) relevant Wikipedia article. Also, note that the great Leonhard Euler already gave a complete parameterization of numbers which can be written as the sum of two cubes in two distinct ways more than three centuries ago. The relevant entries can be found [here](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6952c/f599) and [here](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6952c/f600).

Comment: Visit a friend in hospital by taxi, and look at the license plate number of the taxi :-)

Comment: @gnasher729 The answer is 91, not a taxicab number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is also known as the Hardy-Ramanujan number:

$1729=1^3+12^3=9^3+10^3$

It can be easily found with computer research (or even by hand, if you insist), and I don't think an elegant proof is known. More generally, the $n$th "Taxicab number" is defined to be the smallest integer expressable as $n$ different sums of two positive cubes. More information can be found on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaxicabNumber.html.

Comment: Bzzzt WRONG.  The answer is 91.  Or if you allow trivial solutions, then the answer is zero,

Answer (score 2):

Computer search (or a short hand computation) quickly finds that it's $$91 = 3^3 + 4^3 = (-5)^3 + 6^3$$

Other small examples include $152, 189, 217$.

(Observe that, unlike squares, cubes can be negative.)

Comment: Well, maybe...but then what about $0=1^3+(-1)^3=2^3+(-2)^3$?

Comment: Yes, I omitted the obvious trivial solutions.